# Create numbers based on different probability in R

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate a matrix of data set `i*j`, with `i=2 ; j = 200`, which represent subject and trial separately, and create random number between 0-10 based on trials with different probability. For first subject (`i=1`), the first 100 trials (`j = 1-100`) there is 70% probability to be number 1-5 and 30% probability to be number 6-10, and the probability reverse in trial 101 to 200. For second subject (`i=2`), the first 100 trials (`j = 1-100`) there is 60% probability to be number 1-5 and 40% probability to be number 6-10, and the probability reverse in trial 101 to 200.

I gave an example of 2 subjects because I need to do this with multiple `i` but not only 1 `i`.

Can I work this out with `sample`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are after is [*Stratified Sampling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling).

---

With base R, you can implement stratified sampling via `sample`, but you may need to define a user function like `f` as below

```
f <- function(N, p) {
  c(
    sapply(
      list(p, rev(p)),
      function(v) {
        sapply(
          sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), N, replace = TRUE, prob = v),
          function(x) ifelse(x, sample(1:5, 1), sample(6:10, 1))
        )
      }
    )
  )
}
```

When you use it, you first define a probability list `probs` for each trial, e.g.,

```
probs <- list(c(0.7, 0.3), c(0.6, 0.4))
```

and then run

```
> lapply(probs, f, N = j)
[[1]]
  [1]  2  1  2  5  3  6  9  2  2  2  3  2  3  7  4  5  3  7  1  4 10  2  3  6  8
 [26]  7  8  3  1  2  5  1  4  4  4  2  1  5  5  4  1  6  4  2  9 10  5  1  1  5
 [51]  4  4  3  4  8  4 10  3  2  1  3  4  7  4  2 10  1  4  3  3  5  2  7  6  5
 [76]  3 10  4  2  2  5  1  2  3  2  3  3  2  9 10 10 10 10  3  1  4  3  1  1  5
[101]  8  6  5  9  1  6  1  9 10  4  5  4  6  5  8  2  4 10  6  3  8  5 10  8  8
[126]  8  9  3  8  6  5  7 10  9  6  8  9  5  6  8  4  6  6  7  4  4  8 10 10  6
[151]  9 10  9  7  8  7  3  7  4  6 10  8 10  8  5  6 10  8  9  6  6  1  9  4  8
[176]  1  5 10  7 10  8  7  6  6  5  4  7  7  8  8  1 10  8  5  8  9  4  5  6  7

[[2]]
  [1]  7  9  4  9  5  3  3  9  4  5  6 10  4  5  2  3  2  5  4  5  3  8  5  2  1
 [26]  6  5  3  9  3  9  9  9  8  7  3  4  5  7  3  5  3  5  7  5  3  4  2  6  4
 [51]  7  6  2  7  4  4 10  4 10  2  8 10  3  2  8  1  8 10  8  4  3  2  9  8  4
 [76]  4 10  1  3 10  6  8  6  3  5  2  3  3  9  4  7  5  1  1  1  3 10  5  2  7
[101]  2 10  2  6  8 10 10  7  3  7  3  3  7  1 10  3  4  1  1  8  2  5  2  4  7
[126]  2  7  7  4  9 10  7  1  4  4  9  7  9  9  9  8  4  1 10  6 10  4  4  8  9
[151]  7  8  3  2  9  1  9  7  6  9  1  6  3  9  7  8  5  9  3  8  9  6  5  1  2
[176]  5 10  2  7  8  7  8  8  8  8  8  5  1  1  7  6  3  3  4  2  3  2  3  1  3
```